# Use dynamic defaults for Python's attr package when creating model

Tags: python, attr

I am working with attr to create a meta-model (showing a subset to give the idea),

```
import abc, attr
from attrs import validators
from delensalot.lerepi.core.validator import model

@attr.s
class DLENSALOT_Data:
    """A root model element of the Dlensalot formalism.

    Attributes:
        beam: 
    """

    beam = attr.ib(default=None)



@attr.s
class DLENSALOT_Model:
    """A root model element of the Dlensalot formalism.

    Attributes:
        data: 
    """
    
    data  = attr.ib(default=DLENSALOT_Data(), validator=model.data)
```

A model,
`DLENSALOT_Model()`
then defaults to it's default values as expected.

I would like to have a different default-configuration depending on the user choice, in the sense of  the following:

```
DLENSALOT_Model(defaultsto='A').data.beam
>>> <beam value for default A>
```

```
DLENSALOT_Model(defaultsto='B').data.beam
>>> <beam value for default B>
```

In other words, I'd like to have a way of configuring my meta-model. I am thinking of something like (which doesn't work but I hope it gives the idea),

```
import abc, attr
from attrs import validators
from delensalot.lerepi.core.validator import model

default_dict = {
    'A' : ...,
    'B': ...
}


@attr.s
class DLENSALOT_Data:
    """A root model element of the Dlensalot formalism.

    Attributes:
        beam: 
    """
    defaultsto = attr.ib()
    beam = attr.ib(default=default_dict[defaultsto]['data']['beam'])



@attr.s
class DLENSALOT_Model(DLENSALOT_Concept):
    """A root model element of the Dlensalot formalism.

    Attributes:
        data: 
    """
    defaultsto = attr.ib()
    data  = attr.ib(default=DLENSALOT_Data(defaultsto=defaultsto), validator=model.data)
```

Any suggestions appreciated

I've tried  `attr.Factory(lambda self: .., takes_self = True)`, decorators to post-set defaults, and it's just not working for me..

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`__attrs_post_init__`](https://www.attrs.org/en/stable/init.html#post-init)

```py
import attr

default_dict = {
    'A': {'data': {'beam': 'yummy'}},
    'B': {'data': {'beam': 'spicy'}}
}


@attr.s
class DLENSALOT_Data():
    """A root model element of the Dlensalot formalism.

    Attributes:
        data: 
    """
    defaultsto = attr.ib()
    data = attr.ib(default=None, init=False)

    def __attrs_post_init__(self):
        self.data = default_dict[self.defaultsto]['data']['beam']


print(DLENSALOT_Data(defaultsto='A').data)
```

Output:

```
yummy
```

Comment: Although this may solve the problem by using,
`DLENSALOT_Model(data = DLENSALOT_Data(defaults_to='A'))`
the `DLENSALOT_Model`, in general, consist of many more attributes, and your solution would have me to do
`DLENSALOT_Model(
 data = DLENSALOT_Data(defaults_to='A')),
 attr1 = DLENSALOT_Attr1(defaults_to='A'),
 attr2 = DLENSALOT_Attr2(defaults_to='A'),
...)`
which would be very inconvenient